# Password-based encryption fails when salt value changed

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, salt

Below code uses PBE algorithm, I understand `SALT` array is used to add few bytes to the password provided. But when I tried to remove few elements from that array and when I run the program its giving error.

My question is, `SALT` array used in below program can be modified or not?. If yes why I am getting error when I modified it?.

Please review this code and help me in understanding it. Brief explanation about the program apart from this `SALT` array is very much appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class ProtectedConfigFile {

private static final char[] PASSWORD = "enfldsgbnlsngdlksdsgm".toCharArray();
private static final byte[] SALT = {
    (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12,
    (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12,
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String originalPassword = "secret";
    System.out.println("Original password: " + originalPassword);
    String encryptedPassword = encrypt(originalPassword);
    System.out.println("Encrypted password: " + encryptedPassword);
    String decryptedPassword = decrypt(encryptedPassword);
    System.out.println("Decrypted password: " + decryptedPassword);
}

private static String encrypt(String property) 
throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
    Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
    return base64Encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(property.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}

private static String base64Encode(byte[] bytes) {
    // NB: This class is internal, and you probably should use another impl
    return new BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes);
}

private static String decrypt(String property) 
throws GeneralSecurityException,       IOException {
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
    Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
    pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
    return new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(base64Decode(property)), "UTF-8");
}

private static byte[] base64Decode(String property) throws IOException {
    // NB: This class is internal, and you probably should use another impl
    return new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(property);
}

}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Salt must be 8 bytes long 
  at TransactionTokenUtility.encrypt(TransactionTokenUtility.java:80) 
  at TransactionTokenUtility.generateToken(TransactionTokenUtility.java:144) 
  at TransactionTokenUtility.main(TransactionTokenUtility.java:51) 
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Salt must be 8 bytes long 
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_ab.a(DashoA13*..) 
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(DashoA13*..)
```

Comment: Is that comma needed on the last of the SALT array elements?

Comment: @user2310289 No, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: "*when I run the program its giving error*" > Always, always, always post the error when writing a SO question. Please edit your question and include the stack trace.

Comment: No, Program runs fine with and without comma at ending of SALT.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Salt must be 8 bytes long
 at TransactionTokenUtility.encrypt(TransactionTokenUtility.java:80)
 at TransactionTokenUtility.generateToken(TransactionTokenUtility.java:144)
 at TransactionTokenUtility.main(TransactionTokenUtility.java:51)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Salt must be 8 bytes long
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_ab.a(DashoA13*..)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(DashoA13*..)

Comment: So this exception answers your question.  The SALT must be 8 bytes long.  But I guess it can be modified i.e. maybe any eight bytes are OK.

Comment: I've voted to close as "too localized". The problem is clearly explained in the error message. I can't see this question helping others in the future.

Comment: -1, read error messages before posting a question to SO, especially if that message clearly explains the problem.

Comment: I can see that error, my question asked about explaning the use of SALT array and its functionality, in that array when I increased or decreased bytes its giving error,, So always this SALT array should be 8 bytes only?? Thats my question indirectly. I know that error is coming, am expecting a answer for why it's coming.

Comment: @DuncanJones Nominated for re-opening as the Mahendra Reddy explicitly asked for an explanation on why the exception was handling. Asking why is always permitted in my opinion, even if the exception is clear, and it is a nice reason for pointing to PBKDF2.

Comment: Please note that PBKDF1 (as deployed by the older password based encryption scheme), MD5 and DES are all deprecated and not deemed secure enough for modern cryptographic purposes. Upgrade your cryptography. Never use Sun internal classes (the base 64 encoder/decoder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the salt should contain exactly 8 random octets (read: bytes) according to the older v1.5 PKCS#5 standard and PBKDF1. The Oracle Java implementation (from 2002!) follows this standard. This can be (and has been) verified using the source code available from Oracle.

Standards that requires 8 octets:

- PKCS#5 v1.5
- PBKDF version 1 from PKCS#5 v2.0 onwards (defined for compatibility with PKCS#5)

Standards that require 8 octets minimum (as recommendation):

- PBKDF2 in the PKCS#5 standard v2.0 onwards

The best thing to do is to migrate to PBKDF2. You would have a more secure (NIST accepted) algorithm, and you have more flexibility regarding the salt length.

*Note that the chapter about the Salt (chapter 4) in PKCS#5 talks about a minimum of 8 octets as a minimum security requirement. This is however overruled by the definition of PBKDF1 which defines precisely 8 octets.*

Comment: does PKCS#5 standard says that SALT should be always 8 bytes?. Plz try running that program for 16,32 or 64 bytes , am getting same exception. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I will try at the earliest convenience (which may well be somewhere next week)

Comment: Sorry for the late change, I simply ran out of time...

Comment: +1 Deleted my answer, yours is much better :-)